# Elastic Beanstalk not creating ssl.conf

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache, ssl, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, ebextensions

I am following the [these](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/https-singleinstance-php.html) instructions for enabling HTTPS on the EC2 instance managed by Elastic Beanstalk. I can see that Elastic Beanstalk creates the /etc/pki/tls/certs/server.crt & /etc/pki/tls/certs/server.key files. However, Elastic Beanstalk is not creating the /etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf file. Manually creating the /etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf file, post environment creation, does enable HTTPS though. I am using Apache server.

P.S. I had to change line 3 to mod_ssl : [] (original was mod24_ssl : [])

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are following instruction for EB platform based on Amazon Linux 1 (AL1). However, it seems that you are using **platform based on AL2**, where proxy (httpd or nginx) are setup differently then on AL1. Specifically, they should be in `.plaftorm` folder, not `.ebextentions`. From [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/using-features.migration-al.html#using-features.migration-al.generic):

> Configuration file location – You should place proxy configuration files in the .platform/nginx and **.platform/httpd** directories on all Amazon Linux 2 platform versions.

Further details how to setup `httpd` on AL2 platforms are in [Configuring Apache HTTPD](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/platforms-linux-extend.html).